# Changing Android Manifest file for build automation

Tags: android, regex, bash, sed

I have manifest file which has code for version as follows :

```
android:versionCode="4240"
android:versionName="4.2.4.0"
```

I want to write a shell script that changes "4240" and "4.2.4.0" to value passed as command line argument. "sed" command seems right option, I am new to regx or extended regx used by sed command. can anybody suggest me right way to replace value after *android:versionCode="*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android manifests are XML, which makes `sed` a rather terrible tool for handling them. Instead, use xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/manifest/@android:versionCode' -v 1234 -u '/manifest/@android:versionName' -v 1.2.3.4 manifest
```

More readably:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/manifest/@android:versionCode' -v 1234 \
              -u '/manifest/@android:versionName' -v 1.2.3.4 manifest
```

`/manifest/@android:versionCode` and `/manifest/@android:versionName` are [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) expressions identifying the attributes you want to change.

Comment: You should use `Groovy` and make a task in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: If OP is already using Groovy (or if using it doesn't pose a problem), then that is quite true. @neil: Please let us know. If it is the case, I support closing for duplicate.

Comment: @Wintermute thanks a lot for ur answer. I am going for xmlstarlet.